# Method to create and update a NSMutableDictionary array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been working on a Objective-C iOS app. It pulls down some data from our JSON API, and I've been trying to format it some by cherrypicking objects I want out.

I wrote up a static version that works as I need with my UITableView nicely, however I needed to write a method to handle things more nicely.

```
self.propertyData = @{@"Address": @[ @{ @"Street": _tempPropertyData[@"address"][@"line1"] },
                                   @{ @"City": _tempPropertyData[@"address"][@"line2"] },
                                   @{ @"County": _tempPropertyData[@"area"][@"countrysecsubd"] },
                                   @{ @"Subdivision": _tempPropertyData[@"area"][@"subdname"] },
                                   @{ @"Municipality": _tempPropertyData[@"area"][@"munname"] },
                                   @{ @"Tax Area": _tempPropertyData[@"area"][@"taxcodearea"] }],

                    @"Mortgage": @[ @{ @"Lender": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"lender"][@"lastname"] },
                                    @{ @"City": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"lender"][@"city"] },
                                    @{ @"State": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"lender"][@"state"] },
                                    @{ @"Zip code": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"lender"][@"zip"] },
                                    @{ @"Loan Amount": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"amount"] },
                                    @{ @"Loan Date": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"date"] },
                                    @{ @"Interest Rate": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"interestrate"] },
                                    @{ @"Loan Type": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"loantypecode"] },
                                    @{ @"Deed Type": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"deedtype"] },
                                    @{ @"Term": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"term"] },
                                    @{ @"Maturity Date": _tempPropertyData[@"mortgage"][@"duedate"] }
                                    ]};
```

I wanted to create a function to create each section by calling

```
[self addJsonData:@"Address" Key:@"Street" Value:_tempPropertyData[@"address"][@"line1"]];
```

No matter what I work up, I can't seem to match it, create it or reach my goal. I'm just not understanding it for some reason. self.propertyData is a NSMutableDictionary, and my understanding is that I have created a dictionary with an array of objects, but I guess not.

```
-(void)addJsonData:(NSString*)parent Key:(NSString*)key Value:(NSString*)value {

    if([self.propertyData objectForKey:parent]) {
        // Yes Dictionary with that parent
        NSDictionary *aDic= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value, key, nil];
        NSMutableArray *innerDictArray = self.propertyData[parent];
        [innerDictArray addObject:aDic];
        [self.propertyData setObject:innerDictArray forKey:parent];

    } else {
        // No Dictionary with that parent
        NSDictionary *aDic= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value, key, nil];
        NSMutableArray *innerDictArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:aDic,nil];
        [self.propertyData setObject:innerDictArray forKey:parent];
    }
//    NSLog(@"%@", self.propertyData);
}
```

How can I create and update a dictionary that would match the format of what I'm trying to create from my static version?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having with the code you posted? FYI - `self.propertyData` is not a mutable dictionary. Your static code shown at the top of your question is assigning a non-mutable dictionary full of non-mutable arrays and non-mutable dictionaries.

Comment: At the time the static code, which was my prototype code, was written to a mutable dictionary. Since that time I have removed all that, changed the dictionary to mutable, and wrote the method you see. The problem is the function I wrote does not add to propertyData. I have confirmed that the operation is works, and it does in fact execute the code in the else block, but the end result remains that propertyData in the NSLog is "(null)".... which now that I think about it.. I did not init propertyData within the viewDidLoad.. problem solved. :D - Thanks!

Comment: You should delete your question at this point.

Comment: Nah, It could help someone else in the future. Beside, any idea why the function may be reshuffling the input vs chronological order it was added?

Comment: There are many existing questions where the problem was forgetting to initialize the array. I picked one of the many as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I forgot to init the NSMutableDictionary. The method itself works just fine.

```
self.propertyData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```